# Firebase FCM silent push notifications for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with silent notifications on iOS.

When my application is in background, I don't receive silent notification sent by FCM. But if I try to send directly to APNS, the notification is successfully received.

This is the JSON sent to FCM:

```
{ 
"to" : "<token>",
"priority": "high",
"content_available": true,
"data" : {
  "<key>" : "<string>",
  "<key2>" : "<string>"
}
```

}

This is the JSON sent directly to APNS:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "content-available": 1
  },
  "<key>": "<string>",
  "<key>": "<string>"
}
```

I have already tried to remove the "priority" key because I saw someone saying that I shouldn't set the priority if the "content_available" is already set. It didn't work.

1. I have "Push Notifications" enabled in XCode > Capabilities.
2. I have "Remote notifications" checked in Background Modes in XCode > Capabilities.
3. The FCM notifications are working fine when app is in foreground and sometimes when the app is in background.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Remove **"notification"** key value pair and add **"content_available": true**

It will look like this

```
{ 
    "to" : "...",
    "priority": "high",
    "content_available": true,
    "data" : {
      ....
    }
}
```

This should make it a silent APNS and you need to handle with corresponding APNS delegate methods.

You will need to handle this through delegates
Refer this firebase documentation for details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Answer (score 5):

I found an workaround. I put an empty value for "sound" in "notification" field and the silent notifications are delivered even when the application is in background.

```
{ 
    "to" : "...",
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "sound": ""
    },
    "data" : {
      ....
    }
}
```

My hunch is that Apple does not allow silent notifications with a 'high' priority and somehow "notification": {"sound": ""} tricks the APNS that this notification is not a silent one.

Comment: Right after you set the notification object, it becomes a normal push notification. It's not a silent push notification at al.

Comment: what to do to send the silent notification through FCM message console ?

Answer (score 2):

I was working on Firebase silent push notification using nodejs. When I tried below code its was working fine. When I was adding "priority": "high" and "content_available": true it was giving below error.

> Worked below code

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount ="...."; //service account path
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let  fcmToken = "...."; // Your token
let message ={
    "token": fcmToken,
    "data": {
        "updateApi": "activity"
    }
} 

admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) =>{
    console.log('Successfully sent notification:', response);
})
  .catch((error) =>{
    console.log('Error while sending notification:', error);
});
```

> Error when I added the **priority** and **content_available** in message object

```
{ code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
     message: 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "priority" at \'message\': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "content_available" at \'message\': Cannot find field.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

Comment: Yes, Just don't pass *priority* and *content_available* in above message object

Comment: Then how to control the values of these. Where I can change priority and content_available values?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a cloud function, I found a lot of the information, even in the official documentation was out of date, or different from the typescript interfaces.

This finally worked for me.  Rather than set `alert: ""`, just *leave it out*, it's optional.  For custom properties, you can add to message.apns.payload.
The fcmToken should be the user's token from their device.

```
  const message: TokenMessage = {
    token: fcmToken,
    apns: {
      headers: {
        "apns-priority": "5",
      },
      payload: {
        aps: {
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
        my_custom_parameter: true,
      },
    },
  };

  admin
    .messaging()
    .send(message)
    .then(() => {
      // do something.
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      functions.logger.error(
        "Error sending push notification: " + error.toString()
      );
      // Do something.
    });
};
```