# Notification Service Extension does not handle data messages when using Firebase Data Message

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

The app is on both iOS and Android, for this notification to work on both platforms, I removed `notification` field from notification json payload. But now iOS does not handle this notification when in background.

This one works on iOS but it has `notification` field which I do **not** want.

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
        "...",
        "..."
    ],
  "priority": "high",
  "notification": {
    "body": "Notification Body.",
    "title": "Notification Title"
  },
  "data": {
    "userId": "11111",
    "badge": 10
  }
}
```

This one works in android but **not** working on iOS when in background:

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
        "...",
        "..."
    ],
  "mutable_content": true,
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
    "click_action": "AndroidIntent"
    "message": "Notification Body",
    "myDataField": "11",
    "location": "3",
    "imageurl": "http://image.com/13fd.png"
  }
}
```

The bottom one does not even enter my Notification Service Extension. How do I make sure my Notification Service Extension is called without adding a `notification` field on my json?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807397/firebase-fcm-silent-push-notifications-for-ios?rq=1

Comment: Did the above one with "notification" key in the payload enters Notification Service Extension? I'm having same problem as well. My Notification Service doesn't get called that's why I cannot create a thumbnail on my notification via FCM.

Comment: did you solve it bro.... can you share the solution please.....

Comment: are you solve it bro I'm stuck in the same problem .... please share the solution

Comment: Anyone lucky? There is a bounty on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958704/handling-data-notification-only-in-both-ios-and-android-fails

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thoughts. I was thinking of receiving data from `firebase` and *push local notification* with customized title and body with notification service extention. This idea worked fine in foreground by implementing `didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:` in `appDelegate` to receive `userInfo`.

But it didn't work in background mode by enabling `content_available`. you send notification using *APN Servers* not *Fcm Servers* relating to [firebase docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) I suggest to have a look in `content_available` and `mutable_content`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `content_available` since this is the property to handle silent notifications.