# onMessage is not called while data only message on ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am doing fcm integration to flutter demo application.onMessage method is not called when data only message is sent through postman in any condition(forground,background,killed.) (ios physical device iphone5s).

I have tried notification +data message it is working properly.  as described in firebase_messaging plugin.

```
{
 "to" :"firebase-token",
 "data" : {
     "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
     "body" : {
        "message":"this is data message"
     },
     "title" : "data title",
     "content_available" : true,
     "priority" : "high"
    }
}
```

here is content of notification request of postman

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    Fimber.d("onMessage: $message");
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "onMessage: $message",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    );
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    Fimber.d("onLaunch: $message");
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "onLaunch: $message",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    );
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    Fimber.d("onResume: $message");
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "onResume: $message",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    );
  },
);
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
    .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
  Fimber.d("Settings registered: $settings");
});
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
  Fimber.d("token: $token");

});
```

it is in init state of homepage.
 i have permission notifications in ios and working well with notification+data.
-result should be as described in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab-

Comment: Can you show us the code that is not working properly ?

Comment: udated my Question with code....

Answer (score 0):

-i have found work around from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41162146/10561246)
add notification and sound to json like this

```
{
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "to" :"fcm-token",
 "notification":{
        "sound": ""
 },
 "data" : {
   "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
   "body" : {
        "message":"3:57pm"
   },
  "title" : "data title",
  "content_available" : true,
  "priority" : "normal"
 }
}
```