# Firebase silent notification is not working with iOS13

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, ios13

I'm trying to send a silent notification through firebase services.
But the process is not working (but normal notification is working fine)

I've tried various of payload for the script.

This is one of the payload samples.

```
 $payload = [

        'to' => <USER_TOKEN>,

        'content_available' => true,

        'priority' => 'high',

        'data' => [
            'id' => '68f75319-c736-4b4c-df3f-08d792b6d1b0',
        ],

        'apns' => [
            'headers' => [
                'content_available' => true,
                'apns-priority' => '5',
                'apns-push-type' => 'background',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Please let me know if there any changes to be made to the payload.

Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: The following suggestion is working:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807397/firebase-fcm-silent-push-notifications-for-ios?rq=1