# Sending Background Notifications With FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send background notifications using FCM, however, I have not been able to get it to work. I can get push notifications to work fine, just not background notifications. I have looked at numerous sources on this subject and tried many things, however, nothing seems to be working.

1. I have "Push Notifications" enabled in XCode > Capabilities.
2. I have "Remote notifications" checked in Background Modes in XCode > Capabilities
3. I have registered the device token properly and configured APNs properly (Push notifications work)

The problem is this method never gets called in the background:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Some of the JSON formats I've tried are

```
{
   "notification": {
      "title": "title",
      "body": "body",
    },
    "data":{  
      "name":"name",
   },
   "content_available": true,

   "apns":{
    "headers":{
      "apns-priority": "5",
      "apns-push-type": "background"
    },
  },
    topic: topic,
  }
```

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "title":'title",
      "body":"body",
   },
   "notification":{  
      "title":"mytitle",
      "body":"mybody",
      "content_available": true
   },
   topic: topic
}
```

And many others.

I have used different combinations of "priority" and "content_available": true. Including "notifications" and not including them. I have put "content_available": true on different levels, and nothing seems to be working.

I've looked at:

[FCM background notifications not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899712/fcm-background-notifications-not-working-in-ios)
https://izziswift.com/fcm-background-notifications-not-working-in-ios/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

[Firebase FCM silent push notifications for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807397/firebase-fcm-silent-push-notifications-for-ios)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive

And many other stack overflow posts.

With some of the JSON configurations that I have tried, I get this error and I'm not sure why:

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.on.code (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)
    at process.on.err (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)
```

I'm really struggling and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm running into a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put `contentAvailable: true`

Comment: Where? I'm with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try add code in AppDelegate:

```
'Messaging.messaging().delegate =  self'

'Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnable = true'

'Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true'
```