# Flutter - Display AndroidNotification easily with flutter_local_notifications?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

From the official documentation:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
});
```

`message.notification.android` also provides an `AndroidNotification` object.

My question is, rather than creating various objects such as `AndroidNotificationDetails` and `NotificationDetails` to show a notification, can I simply pass this `RemoteNotification` or `AndroidNotification` and display it using **flutter_local_notifications**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when sending the message with only the `data` payload, that would be a silent notification. You can use the information there to create the notification and past it on to the `flutter_local_notifications`. E.g.

```json
{
  data: {
    'message': 'Some message'
    'value_1': 'Some value'
  },
  topic: 'some_topic'
}
```

Check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902183/4044241) in case you are also doing it for iOS.