# iOS background handler not getting invoked for Firebase push notifications in release mode

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem where the background handler for Firebase push notifications is never invoked when I send a message in the TestFlight release of my app. The foreground handler seems to work fine, but the background handler doesn't.

Here's the message payload I'm sending:

```
{
    "registration_ids": "$ids",
    "notification": {
        "body": "$body",
        "title": "$title",
        "subtitle": "$subtitle",
        "badge": 0,
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "data": {
        "amount": "120"
    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "mutable-content": 1,
                "content-available": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Dart code is as follows:

```
void main() async {
  // Initialization and other code
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    // ... foreground handling code which works fine
  });
  
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await ApiCall.test();
  await HomeWidget.saveWidgetData<String>('amount', message.data["amount"]);
  await HomeWidget.updateWidget(name: 'HomeWidgetProvider', iOSName: 'HomeWidget');
}
```

It's worth noting that:

The ApiCall.test() function logs to my server, and I don't see any logs when the app is in the background, which means the handler isn't invoked.
The HomeWidget functions handle updating a widget on the iOS home screen.
The foreground handler (inside onMessage.listen) is working perfectly. The issue is only with the background handler.

The `flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.5, on macOS 13.6 22G120 darwin-arm64, locale en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.2.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.0)
[✓] Network resources
```

Any insights on why the background handler might not be getting invoked would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its bit late.

I had same issue, when i send test notification from postman,

The apps are in background state: **I got notification pop up**,  but the `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` never invoked..

I try many solution, and this my current solution:

add `content-available` to your payload body like below:

```
{
  "to": "fcm token",
  "content_available": true, // <<<<< add this line 
  "notification": {
    "title": "test",
    "body": "sad"
  },
  "data": {
    "data": "with title again"
  }
}
```

I had tested it. the `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` will invoked when its new notification pop up on background.

---

### Silent notification

if you want to trigger `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` in the background state without pop up any notification:

- in `android` we only need to remove `title` and `body` from the `notification`.
- But for `iOS` you have to remove whole `notification`

```
{
  "to": "",
  "data": {
    "data": "invoke background method"
  },
  "content_available": true
}
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42902183/12838877