Flutter Firebase iOS background handler not working
I know this has been asked before, but this query is slightly different.
I am sending a push notification to an iOS Flutter app. Foreground handling works correctly. Background/killed mode works in that a notification message appears in the system tray and if the user clicks on that message is opens the app and the message details are sent through.
However if I put the app in the background, send a message, I DON'T click on the system tray notification but instead just bring the app back to the foreground, I can see the background handler/listener hasn't done anything. So if the user (ahem, client) has the app in the background and ignores the system tray notification, brings the app to the foreground themselves, no message data is received.
Additionally, inclusion of an image is also being totally ignored.
The xCode capabilities include Background Modes (Background fetch and Remote notifications), and Push Notifications.
My payload looks like this:
"message": {
    "token": "my-token-here",        
    "data": {
        "data_value_1": "DATA VALUE 1 test",
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "NOTIFICATION Title",
        "body": "NOTIFICATION Body",
    },
    "apns":{
      "payload":{
         "aps":{
            "mutable-content": 1,                 
            "content_available": 1, 
         }
      }, 
      "headers": {
       "apns-priority": "10",
      },
      "fcm_options": {
         "image": 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/240_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg'
      }
      }

      }

In addition to the FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen and FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen handling (which both work), I include this in my main.dart file, which doesn' seem to be working:
void main() async{
WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlufluttertterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  ...
  ...  
@pragma('vm:entry-point') 
Future<void>firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async { 
    print('listener hit (background)...message is received!!!!!!!!!!'); 
    //THE ABOVE NEVER TRIGGERS!; 
} 
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler); 
await Firebase.initializeApp( options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform );    
runApp(MyApp()); 
}

I've checked all the documents on Firebase and similar posts but I can't get it working...
According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages:

When in the BACKGROUND, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and ONLY handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.

This says to me that placing an app from the background to the foreground without pressing the notification that comes through system tray, will ignore the message entirely. So the question is, why then does "firebaseMassagingBackgroundHandler" exist? Is this just for Android?

The behaviour you describe is expected. If you don't include the content-available:1 payload, your app does not get any details about the notification unless the user taps it.   Notifications are. It a guaranteed method to deliver data to your app.  The fcm_options payload is not defined by Apple and so the operating system won't do anything with that.

I also tried adding content-available: 1 but no change. I'll update the payload.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164628/ios-background-handler-not-getting-invoked-for-firebase-push-notifications-in-re ?

yep, tried all that too. Adding "content_available": true where they mention it doesn't work anymore (that was for legacy version). It has to be sent inside "apns"

@Delmontee are you saying you got this working by adding content_available to apns, not aps? Was it content-available or content_available? I've tried both but had no luck.

@Chris Wickens
I haven't got it working

@Delmontee the issue for me was on the backend, needed to be content-available: 1 inside aps but I was accidentally overwriting the aps struct with badge info before the message was sent. I recommend hooking up your Firebase credentials to the firebase_messaging example app and using the node script to send the push, that should help you understand whether the issue is client-side or server-side. Also check that Background App Refresh is enabled in the app settings on your iOS device. Good luck!

I have found a simple workaround after facing this problem for a while.
You can handle receiving the notification natively with swift code and use method channels to send the notification object to your flutter code.
First your AppDelegate.swift should look like this:
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
let methodChannelName = "com.example.app"
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
     FirebaseApp.configure()
     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
     application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}

   // Setup method channel
  if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
    let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: methodChannelName, binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

    // Method channel handler (if needed for other purposes)
    methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) in
      // Handle method channel calls here if needed
    }
  }
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
 func application(application: UIApplication,
               didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
 }
 override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  // Handle the notification data here and pass it to Dart
  if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
    let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: methodChannelName, binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

    // Passing the userInfo to Dart
    methodChannel.invokeMethod("handleMessageBackground", arguments: userInfo) { _ in
      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
  } else {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
  }
 }
}

And then in your Main.dart after initializing Firebase add the following:
 const MethodChannel _platform =
MethodChannel('com.example.app');

_platform.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
  if (call.method == "handleMessageBackground") {
    final RemoteMessage message = RemoteMessage(
        notification: RemoteNotification(
            title: call.arguments["aps"]["alert"]["title"],
            body: call.arguments["aps"]["alert"]["body"]),
        data: Map<String, dynamic>.from(call.arguments));
    await handleMessageBackground(message);
  }
});

Now whenever you receive a notification even if the app is terminated or in the background, it will be directed to flutter and your background handler will run successfully.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

main.dart file
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(child: MyApp());
}


Add the following lines to the application method in the AppDelegate.m/AppDelegate.swift file of your iOS project.

Objective-C:
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
  [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = (id<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>) self;
}

Swift:
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}

2.AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter


import flutter_local_notifications  // add this line

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
 
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    }


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    } 

// add this line

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

ios notification permission
await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestPermissions(
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          );

All of this checks the working iOS to properly integrate your code

Thanks but the first point gave me errors :S

which part error @Delmontee

If we go to method_channel_messaging.dart, we see that the registerBackgroundMessageHandler implementation does not exist under iOs
Let's see
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart#L191
@override
Future<void> registerBackgroundMessageHandler(BackgroundMessageHandler handler) async {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform != TargetPlatform.android) {
        return;
    }
}


Should we comment that code or what?
